# Instantiating an object in Delphi without using a variable

Tags: delphi

```
TObject.Create().method;

Method(TObject.Create);
```

Does this type of memory call allocate on the heap or the stack? Does it need to be released?

Answer (score 5):

Delphi class instances are always allocated on the heap, and yes, they need to be released when you are done using them <sup>1</sup>, via `TObject.Destroy()` (which `TObject.Free()` calls), eg:

```
obj := TObject.Create;
try
  obj.method;
finally
  obj.Free;
end;
```

```
obj := TObject.Create;
try
  Method(obj);
finally
  obj.Free;
end;
```

```
procedure Method(obj: TObject);
begin
  ...
  obj.Free;
end;

Method(TObject.Create);
```

```
function Method(obj: TObject): TObject;
begin
  ...
  Result := obj;
end;

Method(TObject.Create).Free;
```

And so on. Any object you `Create` with a constructor must be `Destroy`'ed with a destructor.

<sup>1: if you are running your code on a platform that uses [ARC for object lifetime management](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) (currently iOS, Android, and Linux), objects are reference counted and released automatically for you.</sup>

Comment: Even with ARC I guess there could be leaks if nothing actually takes a reference. For instance if the function being called is a const parameter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, and that is a recurring mistake that people do make with ARC - directly instantiating objects in `const` function parameters. The compiler isn't always smart enough to create a hidden variable to hold a reference (certainly not for object-based ARC, and only sometimes for interface-based ARC).

Comment: If Method takes an interface parameter which the object implements, it is automatically freed. Method(bla: ISomeInterface)

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why did you use .Free() in your first two blocks of code? Isn't .Destroy() sufficient?

Comment: @dummzeuch: yes, but if you have a method with a const interface parameter, i.e. `procedure Method(const I: IMyInterface)` and then do `Method(MyObject.Create)`, this can cause problems, even if `MyObject` implements the interface. The refcount is 0. Only if you do `Method(MyObject.Create as IMyInterface)`, things are safe.

Comment: @Günther: Perhaps, sometimes, using `Free` is too much. But if each time, you must decide whether to use `Free` or `Destroy` directly, each time you can make a mistake, and your choice can also become invalid if your code changes. So get in the habit of **always** using `Free` and **never** `Destroy` directly (except, of course, from another destructor) and you greatly reduce the risk of making mistakes. That is also the recommendation Borland and later producers of Delphi have always given out. **ALWAYS USE `FREE`**. In most situations, that is the only proper way to free anyway.

Comment: @dummzeuch yes, but the OP's question is not about interfaces.

Comment: @RemyLebeau he doesn't rule out interfaces either.